Ubuntu 22.04 cant boot
I'm having this issue where whenever I   try to boot, I get stuck on a black screen right before the login page. About a year ago, I  upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, I had alot of problems with the upgraded but thats alright now. Now yesterday I  upgraded to 22.04 and it worked flawlessly only issue being that I had to reinstall "ubuntu-desktop" because of the side panel not appearing. A little bit later I got a pop-up message saying I can upgrade to ubuntu 24.04, which I did. However it failed for some reason and I don't remember why anymore. I rebooted and now it doesn't reach the login page.
Sorry for sounding like a potato, but I don't really know what happened. I'm willing to do send photos and stuff just let me know.
Thanks!

The upgrade to 24.04 should not have come up yet as far as I know. Was scheduled for later this month. As for as your previous upgrade if you had to reinstall the desktop the upgrade was not 100 percent. My personal suggestion due to previous problems back up all data and do a fresh complete install of 24.04

Thanks for the quick response. Are you saying that there is no 24.04 update? And how can I have gotten it if it's not out yet? And how go I do a "fresh complete instal of 24.04"?

Boot the live media and do an install choose erase and install
